# No other browser except firefox is loading immediate changes in CSS file

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

I am making a website using PHP. While completing it I tested it on Firefox only. Today when I tried to test it on other browsers (Opera, Chrome & Internet Explorer) I found some problems in my CSS. When I made changes to my CSS file, none of these browsers except Firefox is showing changes made in the CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">
```

So far what I have tried after Googling for a long time is

- Cleared Cache memory of browser
- Put "?v='+1 everytime'" at end of style.css
- Refresh the webpage using 'ctrl+f5', 'ctrl+r' etc.

Any help ? Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you tried Shift + Refresh?

Comment: yeah i have tried...

Comment: Are you perhaps using a caching solution on your server?

Comment: @AlexDenisov yeah i am testing it on localhost...

Comment: Are you viewing from a laptop/PC or a mobile device?

Comment: @Martin I am using Laptop/PC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour by most browsers. Whenever you try to load a page, if any resources are already present in browsers' cache, they will be loaded from there.

You have two options:

1. disable browser cache for your preferred browser (some browsers allow you to disable cache for specific domains)
2. make your `HTML` always refresh the resource, by appending a non-repeating parameter to the requested resource file name. I personally use: `?v=1482939287` (where `1482939287` is the timestamp). This will make the browser always refresh the resource, as it will ask for a version that's not existing in browser cache.
   Example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?v=1482939287">`

---

Update: You can flush the cache for a webpage by opening Dev Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>I</kbd>), `right-click`-ing on refresh page arrow (while Dev Console is open) and selecting *Empty Cache and Hard Reload*. That is **emptying** the cache.

You can also **disable** it, as suggested above, by opening Dev Console, going to ***Network*** tab and checking *"Disable Cache"* checkbox right under it. Please note that *cache* is only disabled while your developer console is open.

Comment: Where are you building the website? Is it a local or remote machine? And how long does it take for a change to show up in browser from the moment you make the change on server?

Comment: I am using local server WAMP....On changing its name from style.css to styles.css, its working and showing changes immediately...

Comment: Open Developer Tools in Chrone (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`i`). With it open, `right-click` on refresh button and select `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`. If it just refreshed it means you haven't disabled cache.

Comment: Thanks...Problem solved on Chrome.....What to do for others like Opera, IE etc. ??

Comment: Do you realize you are on a programming Q&A asking people to teach you how to use a browser? Your question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I know Andrei....And i think there is nothing wrong if i am asking a solution of a problem that is related to browser on a programming Q&A site...Anyways you helped me to solve my issue...Thanks for that...

Comment: I updated my answer with instructions on how to disable *cache* in Chrome. As in, load all the page resources every time you reload.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for this. I will list you some of my options below.

### Unique identifiers to files though parameters

Adding a parameter behind the file as a kind of a version number may help.
In php you can use `time()` to get the current timestamp or `unique()` to get a unique string.

### Cache settings server side

You can also find some `.htaccess` settings for caching specific file types on the server side. For performance reasons you should do this for production, too.

### Browser Dev Tools

Another way is to open your Browser Dev Tools `(mostly F12)` while developing. Most browsers like Chrome and FF provides a cacheless enviroment when your Browser Dev Tools are open. As a example in chrome you can disable caching explicit.

### My suggestion

Or even better use Task Runner to accomplish this. The keyword to search for is *'cache bust'*. As example you can run `gulp` for concat, versioning, and let it connect the right css files you want to. This is specially suggested for development phase.

regards
Gkiokan